# Why is Angular replacing my hashtag into %23?

Tags: angularjs

When I redirect with `$location.path(url)`, Angular replaces my `#` with `%23`:

```
var path = $location.path() + "/#" + categoryId;
$location.path(path);
```

How can I make sure Angular isn't replacing my hastag with `%23`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you experience is normal. When you are using $location.path() to set a new path you do  not want to use the # character as there is already one in your URL. If you do it anyway, as in your example, your # (the 2nd in the URL) will automatically be escaped because you can have only one unescaped # in an URL.

Long story short either you absolutely need this # before your categorId and then you would need to use `decodeURIComponent` when retrieving your path. Or more easy I would suggest that you don't use this character and replace your code by :

```
var path = $location.path() + "/" + categoryId;
$location.path(path);
```

Comment: You're right, why use the `#` why I just can use the `/` approach :)

Answer (score 0):

This occurred to me when using `$location.path('#/')` for root. This happens because angular `$location.path` encodes the `#tag` if we append to the front in the path. Instead of `$location.path('#/')` using `$location.path('')` solves the problem for root.

for sub paths use `$location.path('/something')` where angular will append #tag and navigates to the url `<base>/#/something`